# How to add cursor hand for pagination in Datatable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have implemented a table using datatable. it looks fine. But How to add cursor mark as hand while mouseover event in pagination links. 
I tried below,

```
   $('#mytable') .on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
            .on( 'search.dt', function () { eventFired( 'Search' ); } )
            .on( 'page.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Page' ); } ).DataTable();

function eventFired()
{

var spans = document.getElementById('variantTable_paginate').getElementsByTagName('a')

for(var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++){
    spans[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
    console.log(spans[i])
}
}
```

It works while loading a data. once I move to next page or search operation it's not working.

I also tried adding below,

```
<table id="mytable" style="cursor:pointer" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
```

any idea would be appreciable

Comment: Why don't use the `:hover` selector in your css?

Comment: Create a style for the pagination links and include the cursor style cursor:pointer to it